# Service fabric more than one communication listener for service remoting

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am developing few micro services using Azure Service Fabric. I have some use cases which need the communication between micro services and I read about service remoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting. I just wanted to know is it possible to support more than one listeners in a SF application. E.g. I have an existing stateless web api SF application which is having a listener like below

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp, serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpoint"))
        };
    }
```

To the above list, I need to add a ServiceRemotingListener so that I can expose some data from Micro service for others. Is it possible or anything wrong with approach. I have done the Reverse proxy based communication, but bit concerned with the performance(since I am planning to perform a real time read operation from Service 1 to Service 2).

Answer (score 3):

In your `CreateServiceInstanceListeners` method you are returning an array of listeners. This means that it is possible to create multiple listeners. Just add it like you would with any other array:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(serviceContext), "RemotingListener"),
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp, serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpoint"))
    };
}
```

Note that even though the listener name is an optional parameter, you **have to** give your listeners a name. I've also experienced some problems with the service proxy trying to connect to the other endpoint. In order to solve this declare the remoting listener first and your other listeners second.